# Lubuntu: Make Control+Alt+T open a new terminal on top of all windows?

Tags: command-line, lubuntu, shortcuts, lxterminal

I'm using Lubuntu. Whenever I open a terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, it opens lxterminal behind whichever window is currently focused. Is there any way for this shortcut to open lxterminal on top of all currently opened windows?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, I fixed it by adding this to my `~/.config/openbox/lubuntu-rc.xml`:

```
  <applications>
    <application name="lxterminal">
      <focus>yes</focus>
    </application>
    .....
```

This also fixes it for when you press `F4` from `pcmanfm`.